# PHPMailer, not able to deliver certain emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Our company sends out emails through phpmailer to our customers and certain emails never go through to certain people... (emails for .gov, .amec, and others)

If we use the same email address and send them the exact same email in outlook they receive it just fine. Does anyone know whats the issue is? I've been told it could be the headers, but I'm not to familiar with how to solve that.

Here is our mailer code:

```
Note all variables/non-logic has been replaced with {{}} for this example.

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsMail();
    $mail->SetFrom({{from address}}, {{from name}});
    $mail->AddAddress({{address addition}});
    $mail->WordWrap = 70;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = {{subject}};
    $mail->Body = {{body}};
    $mail ->AltBody = {{alt body}};
    $mail->MsgHTML({{msg}});
    $mail->Send();
```

Comment: What MTA are you using on the server? Also, can you send yourself an email and show the raw headers being received?

Comment: I have seen this before where the mail server doesn't send to some addresses - what server are you using. Are you able to verify that mails can be sent to these addresses through this server?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$mail->IsMail();` to `$mail->IsSendmail();`

Also, if you change `$mail = new PHPMailer();` to `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`, it will throw exceptions on errors.

Third, you don't need `$mail->MsgHTML({{msg}});` line - just put all of your message in the `$mail->Body = {{body}};`.

Your code should look like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->SetFrom('myEmail@example.com', 'MyFirst MyLast');
$mail->AddAddress('email@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->WordWrap = 70;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Example Subject';
$mail->Body = $body; // can set using ob_start(); and ob_get_contents();
$mail ->AltBody = 'Alt body message';
$mail->Send();
```

- Footnote: Some servers/email clients will block out emails with certain headers, domains, etc. - there's really no way to check all of the variables because no matter what, *someone* will at some point not be getting every email that you send out. Tools like [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com) can help you sort through some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your mail server logs (of the mail server that phpmailer is using to send these messages) to see what they are showing for these failed delivery attempts.  The logs should shed some light on why these deliveries are unsuccessful.